# How to get the attached self sign certificate in the server spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

my client side i have attached the certificate in the restTemplate  code below . using this rest template i am calling other API(server side) . how to get the certificate in that server side

```
 @Bean(name="custRest")
    @Primary
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        char[] password = "changeit".toCharArray();

        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
                .create().loadKeyMaterial(new File("C:\\java\\java-certificate.der"),null,null)
                .loadTrustMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile("C:\\java\\java-certificate.der"), null,
                        acceptingTrustStrategy)
                .build();

        HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();
        return builder.requestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client))
                .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all step for configuring HTTPS for Spring Boot in article:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate